# Why won't my object save to persistent storage?

Tags: java, android, serialization, persistent-storage

I have a complex object that we can call `MyComplexObject`. I want to save this to persistent storage so that I can retrieve it after the application has been destroyed and recreated. I am using these to methods to pass my object between activities (saving in one activity and loading in the next). I also want to save the object when the application is destroyed (probably in the `onStop()` override)
I can successfully load and save my object between activities but for some reason if I destroy the app on my phone and restart it, a new MyComplexObject is always created and it fails to load the object that was saved before it was destroyed!

My object contains multiple objects that contain multiple objects - all of which implement `Serializable`.

Any ideas on how to be able to save/load my object in a way that will allow me to retain the player's info after the app has been destroyed/recreated?

Even `onDestroy()` and/or on `onStop()` I receive notification that the object has indeed been saved! So I am unsure why it cant load it back when the app is recreated.

```
 public static MyComplexObject Load(Context context){
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = context.getApplicationContext().openFileInput("player1.data");
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            MyComplexObject Game = (MyComplexObject) is.readObject();
            is.close();
            fis.close();
            return Game;
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Load", "creating new game - \n" + e.toString());
            MyComplexObject NewGame = MyComplexObject();
            return NewGame;
        }
    }


    public static void Save(Context context,MyComplexObject Game){
        try{
            FileOutputStream fos = context.getApplicationContext().openFileOutput("player1.data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            os.writeObject(Game);
            os.close();
            fos.close();
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("Save", "Failed to save - \n" + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

Here is the log:

```
07-01 14:24:11.824    3304-3304/? E/#Load﹕ creating new world -
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference
```

here is my onCreate() snippet:

```
MyComplexObject Game;

      @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Game =  LoadGame.Load(this);  //LoadGame is the class with Load(),Save()
    }
```

Comment: what is the logs of the crashes?

Comment: It does not crash at all. Everything works perfectly fine except when i restart the app (close the app from the processes menu and reopen it from the app drawer) it always returns NewGame instead of the Game i had saved `onStop()` when the app was terminated @yshahak

Comment: So what is the logs of the Exceptions?

Comment: Could you use a database?

Comment: @yshahak i have added the log above^

Comment: @frankelydiaz can i store a complex object like this in a database? and how can i do that?

Comment: where you call to the load function?

Comment: @yshahak i call it `onCreate()` of my MainActivity

Comment: Try to use the context.openFileOutput,  or context.getApplication().openFileOutput

Comment: @yshahak could you modify my code to show me exactly what you mean?

Comment: and plz show your onCreate snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
public static MyComplexObject Load(Context context){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = context.openFileInput("player1.data");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        MyComplexObject Game = (MyComplexObject) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return Game;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Load", "creating new game - \n" + e.toString());
        MyComplexObject NewGame = MyComplexObject();
        return NewGame;
    }
}
```

or:

```
public static MyComplexObject Load(Context context){
    try{
        FileInputStream fis = context.getApplication().openFileInput("player1.data");
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        MyComplexObject Game = (MyComplexObject) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return Game;
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Load", "creating new game - \n" + e.toString());
        MyComplexObject NewGame = MyComplexObject();
        return NewGame;
    }
}
```

Comment: IT WORKED! Changed to `context.openFileInput("player1.data")` as you said to do in your first suggestion. Thank you very much. Any ideas why my original line did not work?  (for the sake of learning)

Comment: I think that the getApplicationContext() use sort of context that is wrapped with extra things and in the time that you call getApplicationContext()  the Application class not have enough time to produce this Wrapper, But this could be wrong, this just a guess

Comment: I really wan't to warn you that I have bad experience with Serializable because I didn't add the right settings to the proguard ffile and when I updated version of my app I run into incompatibility with the old version. Take another approach or really read about the proguard require adjusments